# Is it able to pass the VBA variable into ADO SQL statement?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

I use ADO to run the SQL in excel .

The SQL is

```
 sSQLSting = "SELECT  officer ,sum(mkt) from [$DB] where month=2 group by officer"
```

In my system , there is a combobox that consist of the options of YES & NO.

For Yes , the SQL where statement would become `where month=3`

For No , the SQL where statement would become  `where month=4`

In my plan , I want to Dim an integer variable to store `month` in VBA.Then , variable -`month` gets the combobox result so that 3 will be stored into `month`.

---

Lastly , the `integer variable-month` can pass to the SQL statement ***

```
     sSQLSting = "SELECT  officer ,sum(mkt) from [$DB] where month=***group by officer
```

---

**This is my plan .
Is it possible to catch the combobox result and pass the value to SQL statement ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will be able to pass a variable in a SQL statement. It is still a string so you just need to treat it like one.

```
Dim month As Long
 month = 2
 sSQLSting = "SELECT  officer ,sum(mkt) from [$DB] where month= " & month & " group by officer"
```

For a combobox, something like this,

```
Dim month As Long
     month = combobox1.Value
     sSQLSting = "SELECT  officer ,sum(mkt) from [$DB] where month= " & month & " group by officer"
```

Of coarse you will have to edit the code to suit your combo_box name etc.

Comment: now i change the combobox value to 1-12 `.Dim month As Long .AddItem 1 .AddItem 2 .... month = combobox1.Value where month= " & month &" ` it doesn't work

Comment: @Vito if you are using yes/no you will have to pass an integer into the variable.

Comment: How about wt if i change the combobox options to `additem 1 .additem 2 ....  .additem 12  `(12 month in integer format) .Then catch the month by `month = combobox1.Value`.Lastly , pass the value to SQL `where month= " & month &` .it doesn't work

Comment: @Vito what exactly is the combo box out putting?

Comment: the combobox let the user select the month . so the user can select the month from 1-12 .Then the choice will be store into variable `month` and pass to the SQL - where clause  `where month ='&month&" `

Comment: No , it doesn't work .code here :`Dim month As integer `---`AddItem 1 .AddItem 2 .... .Additem 12`  ----  `month = combobox1.Value `  ----  `where month= " & month &" `

Comment: @Vito, not my code , does this work in your original post? `sSQLSting = "SELECT  officer ,sum(mkt) from [$DB] where month=2 group by officer"`

Comment: i find the problem . `where month="&month&"group by`  .there is no space bar between " and group .Do u mind upvote my question ?As i  receive too much downvote recently ,the account has been banned from asking .

Comment: @Vito, Done. Can you change the month variable to a `long` ? Also what error are you getting?  The code should look like this,  `where month=" & month & "group by`